# Solution of $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{ky(m-y)}{m}$ given a value for y

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y = \frac{m}{1+Ce^{-kt}}$, I need to show that this is a solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{ky(m-y)}{m}$. I have successfully done this by finding the derivative with respect to t, substituting the original value for y into the differential equation and showing that both methods give the same answer, but I want to figure it out algebraically as well. Using algebraic integration to solve the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{ky(m-y)}{m}$$ I got an answer of $$y = \frac{mCe^{kt}}{Ce^{kt} - 1}$$ where $C = e^c$.

I can't show that these values for y are equal, though. Can someone please tell me what I should do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close to the desire answer. Just divide both the numerator of $y= \dfrac{mCe^{kt}}{Ce^{kt}-1}$ and denominator by $Ce^{kt}$, and rename $\dfrac{1}{C}$ as $C$, and it will be the same as their answer.